# Dimensiones del puzzle

Tags: c

[Enlace al ejercicio en cuestion](https://www.aceptaelreto.com/pub/problems/v004/02/st/statements/Spanish/index.html)

Entrada de ejemplo

1000

2000

500

Salida de ejemplo

40 25

50 40

25 20

El codigo funciona correctamente, pero a la hora de decirle que el puzzle tiene 64 piezas, me saca 9 8, no debería sacarme 8 8?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int n, i, altura;

    printf("Introduce numero de piezas: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    i=1;
    do
    {
        altura=n/i;
        i++;
    }while(n%altura!=0 || i<=altura);

    printf("%d %d", i, altura);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El código es correcto; el único *detalle* que se te ha pasado es que ...

```
do {
  altura = n / i;
  i++; // <-- SIEMPRE lo incrementas
} while( n % altura != 0 || i <= altura );
```

**Siempre** incrementas `i`, sea cual sea el resultado de `altura = n / i`.

¿ La solución **mas simple** ? Tenlo en cuenta al mostrar el resultado ;-)

```
printf( "%d %d", i - 1 , altura );
```

Comment: Es una posible solución, Trauma, pero solo me sale bien cuando pongo que las piezas del puzzle son 64, se queda 8 8, pero en las otras salidas, por ejemplo, 1000 piezas, en vez de salir 40 25, me sale 39 25, de ahí mi confusión.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGuiber No la marques como *aceptada* si no te vale; dale otra vez al *check* para quitarlo. Ahora cuando pueda te lo miro con mas calma :-)

Comment: vale vale, soy un novato aun por Stack Overflow